# M2E plugin continually updating index

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

I've installed Maven and the m2e Eclipse plugin. For some reason Eclipse is stuck updating indexes whenever I launch it now. Clicking the link on the operation shows the logs below. How can I stop this operation (stop button doesn't work) or fix this?

```
14/08/11 11:50:22 CEST: Updating index central|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
14/08/11 11:50:43 CEST: [WARN] Failure to transfer commons-collections:commons-collections/maven-metadata.xml from http://www.jasperforge.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jaspersoft has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata commons-collections:commons-collections/maven-metadata.xml from/to jaspersoft (http://www.jasperforge.org/maven2): HTTP header is larger than 8192 bytes.
14/08/11 11:50:43 CEST: Downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/maven-metadata.xml
14/08/11 11:50:43 CEST: Downloaded http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/maven-metadata.xml
14/08/11 11:50:44 CEST: [WARN] Failure to transfer commons-digester:commons-digester/maven-metadata.xml from http://www.jasperforge.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jaspersoft has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata commons-digester:commons-digester/maven-metadata.xml from/to jaspersoft (http://www.jasperforge.org/maven2): HTTP header is larger than 8192 bytes.
14/08/11 11:50:44 CEST: Downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-digester/commons-digester/maven-metadata.xml
14/08/11 11:50:44 CEST: Downloaded http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-digester/commons-digester/maven-metadata.xml
14/08/11 11:50:46 CEST: [WARN] Failure to transfer commons-logging:commons-logging/maven-metadata.xml from http://www.jasperforge.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jaspersoft has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata commons-logging:commons-logging/maven-metadata.xml from/to jaspersoft (http://www.jasperforge.org/maven2): HTTP header is larger than 8192 bytes.
14/08/11 11:50:46 CEST: Downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/maven-metadata.xml
14/08/11 11:50:46 CEST: Downloaded http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/maven-metadata.xml
14/08/11 11:50:47 CEST: [WARN] Failure to transfer com.lowagie:itext/maven-metadata.xml from http://www.jasperforge.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jaspersoft has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata com.lowagie:itext/maven-metadata.xml from/to jaspersoft (http://www.jasperforge.org/maven2): HTTP header is larger than 8192 bytes.
14/08/11 11:50:47 CEST: Downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/lowagie/itext/maven-metadata.xml
14/08/11 11:50:47 CEST: Downloaded http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/lowagie/itext/maven-metadata.xml
14/08/11 11:50:50 CEST: [WARN] Failure to transfer jfree:jcommon/maven-metadata.xml from http://www.jasperforge.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jaspersoft has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata jfree:jcommon/maven-metadata.xml from/to jaspersoft (http://www.jasperforge.org/maven2): HTTP header is larger than 8192 bytes.
14/08/11 11:50:50 CEST: Downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jfree/jcommon/maven-metadata.xml
14/08/11 11:50:50 CEST: Downloaded http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jfree/jcommon/maven-metadata.xml
14/08/11 11:50:50 CEST: [WARN] Failure to transfer jfree:jfreechart/maven-metadata.xml from http://www.jasperforge.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jaspersoft has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata jfree:jfreechart/maven-metadata.xml from/to jaspersoft (http://www.jasperforge.org/maven2): HTTP header is larger than 8192 bytes.
14/08/11 11:50:50 CEST: Downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jfree/jfreechart/maven-metadata.xml
14/08/11 11:50:50 CEST: Downloaded http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jfree/jfreechart/maven-metadata.xml
14/08/11 11:50:51 CEST: [WARN] Failure to transfer eclipse:jdtcore/maven-metadata.xml from http://www.jasperforge.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jaspersoft has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata eclipse:jdtcore/maven-metadata.xml from/to jaspersoft (http://www.jasperforge.org/maven2): HTTP header is larger than 8192 bytes.
14/08/11 11:50:51 CEST: Downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/eclipse/jdtcore/maven-metadata.xml
14/08/11 11:50:51 CEST: Downloaded http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/eclipse/jdtcore/maven-metadata.xml
14/08/11 11:50:55 CEST: Maven Builder: AUTO_BUILD 
14/08/11 11:50:56 CEST: Maven Builder: AUTO_BUILD 
14/08/11 11:50:57 CEST: Maven Builder: AUTO_BUILD 
14/08/11 12:12:39 CEST: Refreshing [/timezra.blog.spring_batch/pom.xml]
14/08/11 12:12:42 CEST: Refreshing [/task-basic/pom.xml]
14/08/11 12:12:52 CEST: Refreshing [/springbatch3part/pom.xml]
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Go to <kbd>Window</kbd><kbd>Preferences</kbd><kbd>Maven</kbd> and uncheck <kbd>Download repository index updates on startup</kbd>

Comment: Sorry for the highlighted (highlit?) words on that link.  It's search results.  I could not find anything like a permalink.

Comment: @apollodude217 Try this for a permalink: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/214637/686437/#msg_686437